# Remove literals input value mask on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question has already been asked, but the solutions where not clear for me.

I'm using this code to generate the mask.

```
 $('#cnpjCpf').mask('00.000.000/0000-00');
```

I need you to send: 00000000000000 to DTO

How to remove the .mask and keep the value?

I'm trying to use:

```
function getValuesFromInputs(){

    $('#cnpjCpf').unmask();
}
```

in button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Cadastrar" id="submit" class="btn btn-success"  onclick="getValuesFromInputs()">
```

but it still goes with the mask.

can you help me?

Tanks.

Comment: which mask libray use using?

Comment: Hello, I am using

<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"> </script>

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#getting-the-unmasked-typed-value), the umask is not the way to remove mask from the string. Rather, you should use cleanVal();

```
let cleanedValue = $('#cnpjCpf').cleanVal();
console.log(cleanedValue);
```

**Working example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/mrAhmedkhan/5Lf8h41q/53/

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your reply but it still didn't work

Comment: whats the error or output? how can we help if you dont show anything.

Comment: hello does not have a specific error and returns the value with the mask, does not change the value when sending the form

Comment: <script>
$(function() {
    $("#submit").click( function()
         {
     let cleanedValue = $('#cnpjCpf').cleanVal();
     console.log(cleanedValue);
     
         }
    );
});

</script>

Comment: whats the output?

Comment: <form name="form" id="form" method="POST" th:action="@{/usuario/salvarEscritorio}" class="needs-validation" th:object="${usuarioDTO}" enctype= multipart/form-data> Springboot DTO

Comment: did you see this working example. http://jsfiddle.net/mrAhmedkhan/5Lf8h41q/53/

Comment: what value are you getting on console.log ?

Comment: hello thanks for the help i changed the plugin to

https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js

and the code looks like this:

$ ('# cnpjCpf'). inputmask ({
mask: ['99 .999.999 / 9999-99 '],
autoUnmask: true,
removeMaskOnSubmit: true,});
</script>

It worked for me, thank you very much.